# GoalEnv subclass reset not called

Tags: python, openai-gym

Trying to derive env from GoalEnv.

Does anyone know why this [reset](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/7006c7a182a991b9409c206c56abc121eaffafb5/gym/core.py#L169) function is never called?

```
def reset(self):
        # Enforce that each GoalEnv uses a Goal-compatible observation space.
        if not isinstance(self.observation_space, gym.spaces.Dict):
            raise error.Error('GoalEnv requires an observation space of type gym.spaces.Dict')
        result = super(GoalEnv, self).reset()
        for key in ['observation', 'achieved_goal', 'desired_goal']:
            if key not in result:
                raise error.Error('GoalEnv requires the "{}" key to be part of the observation dictionary.'.format(key))
        return result
```

If I derive my own env from GoalEnv, the base reset is never called - so it never checks observation_space.

Is there an example of when this is actually called?

I tried calling this in my reset:

```
super(MyEnv, self).reset
```

But just got `NotImplementedError`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you call the `reset` via super on `MyEnv` you're actually calling `GoalEnv.reset` which in turn calls `super(GoalEnv, self).reset()` which raises the `NotImplementedError`. I don't think you are supposed to call that reset method like that.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't understand how I can call it at all, if I'm overriding it.